# ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported

Tags: python, django

I am working on a django project, it was working fine untill I added "namespace="polls" in the code below(urls.py) and connected it to "index.html" in 2nd code.

1st- urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),                                
]
```

2nd: index.html:

```
{% extends 'polls/base.html' %}
{% block main_content %}
{% if latest_questions %}
<ul>
    {% for question in latest_questions %}
      <li><a href={% url "polls:detail" question.id %}><b>{{question.question_text}}</b</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
    <p> You don't have any questions. Please add some.</p>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Now when I renserver it shows following error:
*ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.*

Please help, where I am wrong, it could be some missing package/s too as it is recently installed pycharm.
Thank you.

Comment: the code looks correct. try to work only with single or double quotes without mixing them. django sometimes has problems with this. Try to make namespace="polls" to namespace='polls' or best way use duble quotes everywhere how they do in the documentary. It shouldn't make a diffrence but it does.

Comment: Can you show the urls.py for the polls app? You need to define app_name in that file

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but, apparently I have to add "app_name='polls'" in app's url.py  Also changed all "", to ''.

Then the above code is working and server runs properly.
If anyone has explaination for this, feel free to comment.